# Proper Way to Make API Fetch 'POST' with Async/Await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, async-await, fetch-api

I'm working on a project that requires me to make requests to an API. What is the proper form for making a `POST` request with Async/Await?

As an example, here is my fetch to get a list of all devices. How would I go about changing this request to `POST` to create a new device? I understand I would have to add a header with a data body.

```
getDevices = async () => {
  const location = window.location.hostname;
  const response = await fetch(
    `http://${location}:9000/api/sensors/`
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(data.message);
  return data;
};
```

Comment: `await` makes no difference to how the `fetch` API works. You make it a post request in the same way as you would with any other use of `fetch`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

actually your code can be improved like this:

to do a post just add the method on the settings of the fetch call.

```
getDevices = async () => {
    const location = window.location.hostname;
    const settings = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    };
    try {
        const fetchResponse = await fetch(`http://${location}:9000/api/sensors/`, settings);
        const data = await fetchResponse.json();
        return data;
    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }    

}
```

Comment: you can use a`await` to read the response stream as well: `const data = fetch(url); const json = await data.json();`

Comment: In my case, browser is forcing a pre-flight OPTIONS call prior to POST call. I want something like this to await for both OPTIONS & POST call to finish and return the data from POST call. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @StangSpree the preflight call is being done automatically. maybe your backend side is not supporting the call and that could be the reason of the complain of the browser

Answer (score 27):

Here is an example with configuration:

```
try {
    const config = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }
    const response = await fetch(url, config)
    //const json = await response.json()
    if (response.ok) {
        //return json
        return response
    } else {
        //
    }
} catch (error) {
        //
}
```

Answer (score 19):

2021 answer: just in case you land here looking for how to make GET and POST Fetch api requests using async/await or promises as compared to axios.

I'm using jsonplaceholder fake API to demonstrate:

Fetch api GET request using async/await:

```
         const asyncGetCall = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
                 const data = await response.json();
                // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
                 console.log(data);
               } catch(error) {
            // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
                  console.log(error)
                 } 
            }


          asyncGetCall()
```

Fetch api POST request using async/await:

```
    const asyncPostCall = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
                 method: 'POST',
                 headers: {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                   },
                   body: JSON.stringify({
             // your expected POST request payload goes here
                     title: "My post title",
                     body: "My post content."
                    })
                 });
                 const data = await response.json();
              // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
                 console.log(data);
               } catch(error) {
             // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)

                  console.log(error)
                 } 
            }

asyncPostCall()
```

GET request using Promises:

```
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
   // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
   console.log(error)
  })
```

POST request using Promises:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
   body: JSON.stringify({
     // your expected POST request payload goes here
      title: "My post title",
      body: "My post content."
      })
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
   // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
  // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
   console.log(error)
  })
```

GET request using Axios:

```
        const axiosGetCall = async () => {
            try {
              const { data } = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
              console.log(`data: `, data)
           
            } catch (error) {
    // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
              console.log(`error: `, error)
            }
          }
    
    axiosGetCall()
```

POST request using Axios:

```
const axiosPostCall = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',  {
      // your expected POST request payload goes here
      title: "My post title",
      body: "My post content."
      })
   // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
      console.log(`data: `, data)
   
    } catch (error) {
  // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
      console.log(`error: `, error)
    }
  }


axiosPostCall()
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you for taking the time to POST this.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to separate `async/await` and `then` here is an example:

```
const addDevice = async (device) => {
  const { hostname: location } = window.location;
  const settings = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(device),
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  }

  const response = await fetch(`http://${location}:9000/api/sensors/`, settings);
  if (!response.ok) throw Error(response.message);

  try {
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};
```

Comment: What is the problem if we combining?

Comment: @HidaytRahman check Bergi's answer on this topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/2971063