# Why does adding then in a recursive asynchronous function make it return undefined?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a simple asynchronous function that works perfectly. But I need to know what every recursive call returns, so I added `then` (see the line `(*)`). Unfortunately, `result` in such `then`’s is `undefined`, and the result of the whole function becomes `undefined` as well.

```
async function foo(n) {
    try {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return n + await foo(n - 1)
            .then(result => { bar(); }); // (*)
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Why does this `then` break the function? Should I use something else?

Comment: How do you know `result` in `.then(result => { bar(); })` is `undefined`…?

Comment: `console.log(result);` shows that.

Comment: You have `console.log(result)` *inside* that `then` callback, next to `bar()`…?

Comment: besides, `bar` is called but nothing is returned since it's wrapped in a block, hence `n + undefined` should return `NaN` instead.

Comment: Yes, `console.log(result)` is inside `then`, next to `bar()`.

Comment: Fine, so i guess it's joining the `.catch` somehow, hence the `undefined`. Otherwise it would be NaN. May you please add further informations? It's quite hard to give the proper answer right now.

Comment: Adding `.catch` after `.then` didn’t help. I don’t know which information I can give. Without `.then` it works fine, adding `.then` breaks everything.

Comment: By the way, `foo(0)` returns `0`, it’s the only working case.

Comment: @Dyzzet of course it does, since it joins `if (n == 0)`. Your second return will never work as stated above, since you are returning `undefined` on the `await` statement. Besides, what does `bar` do? Besides, it's joining the `catch` of the try catch, not the promise's catch, that's what I meant above.

Comment: Avoid [`await`ing a `.then(…)` chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just how [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) works - it creates a new promise for the result of the callback. Your `result => { bar(); }` callback doesn't `return` anything, so you get `undefined` as the result. You would need to write

```
return n + await foo(n - 1).then(result => { bar(); return result; });
//                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

but really you should not mix `then` callbacks into `async`/`await` code. The equivalent of that corrected code would be

```
const result = await foo(n - 1);
bar();
return n + await result; // (the `await` is unnecessary and should be left out)
```

whereas your original code does

```
const result = await foo(n - 1);
bar();
return n + await undefined;
```