# How to use sync within an async Promise in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, synchronization

When I run the following code:

```
b = async attempt => {
  if (attempt == 5) {
    return;
  }
  console.log("Starting attempt:", attempt);
  b(attempt + 1).then(() => {
    console.log("Finished attempt:", attempt);
  });
};
b(0);
```

The output is:

```
Starting attempt: 0
Starting attempt: 1
Starting attempt: 2
Starting attempt: 3
Starting attempt: 4
Finished attempt: 4
Finished attempt: 3
Finished attempt: 2
Finished attempt: 1
Finished attempt: 0
```

However, I want to call another promise `a` before each recursive call as follows:

```
a = Promise.resolve();
b = async attempt => {
  if (attempt == 5) {
    return;
  }
  console.log("Starting attempt:", attempt);
  a.then(() => {
    b(attempt + 1);
  }).then(() => {
    console.log("Finished attempt:", attempt);
  });
};
b(0);
```

Now the output is:

```
Starting attempt: 0
Starting attempt: 1
Starting attempt: 2
Finished attempt: 0
Starting attempt: 3
Finished attempt: 1
Starting attempt: 4
Finished attempt: 2
Finished attempt: 3
Finished attempt: 4
```

How can I modify the second code block to ensure that the output is the same as the first code block?

Comment: Why did you use an `async` function when not using `await`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are breaking the promise chain by not returning an inner promise `a.then(() => {b(attempt + 1);})`. Adding return statement should help.

Also I would recommend not to mix `async/await` syntax with `.then` and callbacks.

The following code looks more "synchronous" and does the trick.

```js
const a = Promise.resolve();
const b = async attempt => {
  if (attempt == 5) {
    return;
  }
  console.log("Starting attempt:", attempt);
  
  await a
  
  await b(attempt + 1)
  
  console.log(`Finished attempt: ${attempt}`)
};

b(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then the issue is cause by nested promises and calls to asynchronous functions (ie `b(attempt + 1)`) not blocking execution of the enclosing function. This in turn produces unordered, and unexpected logging results.

Consider revising the call to `b()`, by `return` the promise of `b(attempt + 1);` to ensure that the following log: `console.log("Finished attempt:", attempt)` is executed after completion of `b()` completes:

```js
const a = Promise.resolve();
const b = async attempt => {
  if (attempt == 5) {
    return;
  }
  console.log("Starting attempt:", attempt);
  
  await a.then(() => {
  
    /* 
    Return the project of b() here, has similar effect
    to that of await keyword
    */
    return b(attempt + 1); 
  }).then(() => {
    console.log("Finished attempt:", attempt);
  });
};

b(0);
```

Comment: Avoid [`await`ing a `.then(…)` chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572)!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `return` the promise chains that you are creating:

```
const b = attempt => {
  if (attempt == 5) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
  console.log("Starting attempt:", attempt);
  const a = Promise.resolve();
  return a.then(() => {
//^^^^^^
    return b(attempt + 1);
//  ^^^^^^
  }).then(() => {
    console.log("Finished attempt:", attempt);
  });
};
b(0).then(() => {
  console.log("done");
});
```

Only with those `return`s, the caller of the function will be able to wait for the promise. Your first snippet has the same issue. It would've been more obvious if you had omitted the `async` keyword, so that it was clear that `b()` didn't return a promise.

If you want to use `async`/`await`, your code should look like this:

```
const b = async attempt => {
  if (attempt == 5) {
    return;
  }
  console.log("Starting attempt:", attempt);
  await Promise.resolve();
//^^^^^
  await b(attempt + 1);
//^^^^^
  console.log("Finished attempt:", attempt);
};
b(0).then(() => {
  console.log("done");
});
```