# Why Array.map() with async / await returns strange results?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, arrow-functions

Here is a *working* version of my code which returns everything as expected:

```
***.then(r => r.json()).then(async r => {

                    for (let i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
                        let pipeline = r[i];
                        pipeline.collapsed = true;
                        pipeline.levels = await this.getPipelineLevels(pipeline.id);
                    }

                    this.project.pipelines.items = r;
                })
```

Here is the "broken" version that returns strange results:

```
****.then(r => r.json()).then(r => {
                    let pipelines = r.map(async (value) => {
                        let levels = await this.getPipelineLevels(value.id);
                        return {...value, collapsed: true, levels: levels};
                    });

                    this.project.pipelines.levels = pipelines;
```

Strange output in console with `console.log(JSON.stringify(pipelines))` after `*.map()`:

```
[{"_c":[],"_s":0,"_d":false,"_h":0,"_n":false},{"_c":[],"_s":0,"_d":false,"_h":0,"_n":false}]
```

What's happening here?

Comment: Because `.map` doesn't actually `await` it's passed callback.

Comment: `this.project.pipelines.levels = await Promise.all(pipelines);`

Comment: Also avoid [`await`ing a `.then(…)` chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Array.map` doesn't actually `await` it's passed callback. It doesn't care that you marked it's callback as `async`.

Just `Array.map` your Promises then pass them to `Promise.all` and let that await everything (in-parallel) for you.

```js
const getPipelineLevels = id => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve({ id: id, foo: 'bar' }), 500)
})

const idx = [1,2,3,4,5]

const tasks = idx.map(id => {
  return getPipelineLevels(id)
    .then(value => ({ ...value, bar: 'baz' }))
})

Promise.all(tasks)
  .then(results => {
    console.log(results)
  })
```

Comment: Thank you, but a lot of unnecessary code lines :) What @gleam suggested fits better for me.

Comment: @AndrewShmig Err, what's an "unnecessary code line"? I can put this through WinZip so it becomes 0 and 1's if that's what floats your boat.

Comment: I understood everything ok, don't worry, but that's just not my coding style. That's all. Thanks again!

Comment: @AndrewShmig I don't think you understand. gleam's previous answer was mostly OK but not entirely correct. This might not be "your style" but it's correct. In any case, gleam has adjusted his so it's correct.

Comment: Thought about this a little bit more... you are abs right. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
.then(async r => {
    let pipelines = await Promise.all(r.map(async (value) => {
        let levels = await this.getPipelineLevels(value.id);
        return {...value, collapsed: true, levels: levels};
    }));
    this.project.pipelines.levels = pipelines;
});
```

---

`Array.map(async (value) => {...})` returns an array of Promises.

This solution would also be faster than what the OP was trying to achieve anyway since it awaits in-parallel.

And notice that you should to [avoid awaiting a .then(…) chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385676/whats-wrong-with-awaiting-a-promise-chain/54387912#54387912).

Comment: FWIW this solution would also be faster than what the OP was trying to achieve anyway since it awaits in-parallel. But really there's no need for  `async` in `.map`. Just map the promises and let `Promise.all` await them. If you need to modify the value of the Promise, just attach a `.then` to each Promise inside `.map` and do your work there.

Comment: @NikKyriakides - May I use your comment to extend an answer?

Comment: @NikKyriakides, thank you for more exact explanation! @gleam, doh... haven't seen that `map` with `async` returns promises... thanks!

Comment: @gleam Sure you can, I've written up an answer as well which I think is more correct. If you implement what I've done there I'll delete mine.

Comment: That's not implementing the same suggestion.  That's whole-sale cut-and-paste.

Comment: @gleam, you have entirely changed the answer I was accepting. Why?

Comment: @AndrewShmig Because this one is correct, the previous wasn't.

Comment: I am trying to put all clever-things in one answer :)

Comment: @NikKyriakides, why the prev wasn't? Can you explain? Is it a working solution? yes, it works. Then why it's not correct?

Comment: @AndrewShmig Because using `async` in a `.map` served no purpose. Also posts here are meant to help others as well so the OP generalising his example like I did is likely to help that purpose.

Comment: @NikKyriakides async in map has effect. You can use `await` so you don't need to use Promises inside callback ;)

Comment: Err no. `.map` doesn't await each promise in each iteration. In the context of this question it has no effect. That's the point of the question.

Comment: I am agree. In the context of this question it has no effect. But this case is still possible.

Comment: If you believe your previous answer has merits of it's own, rollback your answer to what it was and I'll undelete my answer. Don't let me influence you into what your answer should be.