# Can await and then be mixed in one implementation?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm wondering if await and .then can be used in the same async function? 
Here is my function:

```
uploadImageToImgur: async function (file) {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  const url = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
  reader  = new FileReader();

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

  reader.onloadend = async function () {
    let { result } = reader;

    try {
      const request = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          "Authorization": 'my auth',
        },
        body: result.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg|gif);base64,/, "")
      })
      .then((response) => {
        response.json()
        .then(data => {
          resolve(data.data.link)
        })
      });
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  }
});
},
```

Then I call this function in another one where I save the object to indexedDb with the link i've got from the imgur API.

```
this.uploadImageToImgur(image)
  .then((image) => {
    let db = this.dbOpen.result,
        tx = db.transaction('EventsStore', 'readwrite'),
        store = tx.objectStore('EventsStore');

    event = store.put({ title, location, description, summary, date, time, image });
    //rest of the code
  });
```

Why did I choose this approach? Because when I used only await keyword (without promise constructor), data was adding to the db before promise was resolved ;/ What was not what I wanted (probably I made a mistake somewhere.. idk).

My question is if the code above is the correct way to do that (it works as intended) or should I refactor it? If so, please tell me how. This question is rather informative for me than related with a specific problem.
Thank You.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, you can use mix `await` and `then` syntax - they both work on promises - but [you shouldn't do so in the same function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572).

But that's not the main issue in your code. The problem is the use of the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) in the `uploadImageToImgur` function. Do not use `async function`s as callbacks. Do not create promises in `then` callbacks without `return`ing them - rejections of `response.json()` are not caught by your code.

Yes, you will need the `Promise` constructor to [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) the reader, but that's it. Factor it out inside its own function so that you don't lead yourself into temptation. That `if (file)` condition inside the executor led to your promise being never resolved in some cases!

Cleaned up:

```
function readDataUrl(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      resolve(this.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = reader.onabort = reject; // don't forget this!
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}

uploadImageToImgur: async function(file) {
  const url = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
  if (file) {
    const result = await readDataUrl(file);
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Authorization": 'my auth',
      },
      body: result.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg|gif);base64,/, "")
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    return data.data.link;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it convention to leave `reject` to its default implementation?

Comment: @Slaiyer I don't know about "convention", but yes, if it is possible (and useful) then I would recommend to avoid wrapping `resolve` and `reject` in an unnecessary extra function. In this case, I expect the `onerror` callback to be called with the error as the argument, so it made sense to me. If you want to reject with a custom error/message, sure, go ahead with a function that rejects with that.