# React cannot update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I can't figure why I can't update my state (see setCoords). The request returns with a 200 code and the elements I'm trying to retrieve exists : [image]

Here is my code :

```js
const App = () => {
    const [city, setCity] = useState("");
    const [forecast, setForecast] = useState(null);
    const [coords, setCoords] = useState({});

    const handleSearchChange = ev => {
        setCity(ev.target.value);
    };

    async function onSearch() {
        if (city) {
            await apiGet(`/geo/1.0/direct?q=${city}`)
                .then(r => r.json())
                .then(r => setCoords({lat: r[0].lat, lon:r[0].lon})); // doesn't't set anything

            await console.log(coords) // console logs {}
            await apiGet(
                `/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${coords.lat}&lon=${coords.lon}&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts`
            )
                .then(r => r.json())
                .then(r => setForecast(r));
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems that you forgot to execute `onSearch` function in the given code

Comment: I did not include the whole code but the function is executed.  (see the accepted answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to note is that don't mix `await` with `then` (More on this: [Can await and then be mixed in one implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54574662/can-await-and-then-be-mixed-in-one-implementation)). Since you are using `async`, I recommend you change all to `await`, like below

Another thing to note is `setStates` calls (i.e `setCoords` and `setForecast` and `setCity`) is **asynchronous** by nature, meaning that an immediate `console.log` after setting state will **not** log the just-updated value. Instead, React will schedule those setState onto the next render - therefore, you can only see/access the most updated values in the next render cycle. If you want to log values, you can put them as inside a `<pre>` tag in your HTML, or do `console.log` at the beginning, like below:

```js
const App = () => {
    const [city, setCity] = useState("");
    const [forecast, setForecast] = useState(null);
    const [coords, setCoords] = useState({});

    console.log("City", city, "Forecast", forecast, "Coords", coords);

    const handleSearchChange = ev => {
        setCity(ev.target.value);
    };

    async function onSearch() {
        if (city) {
            const resNonJson = await apiGet(`/geo/1.0/direct?q=${city}`)
            const resJson = await resNonJson.json())
            const item = resJson[0];
            setCoords({lat: item.lat, lon: item.lon}));

            // Note that `setState` is async so console.log will not get the just-updated value
            console.log(coords) // {}
            console.log(item) // {lat:..., lon:...}
            const resNonJson2 = await apiGet(
                `/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${item.lat}&lon=${item.lon}&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts`
            )
             const resJson2 = await resNonJson2.json())
             setForecast(resJson2);
        }
    }
    ... (other codes that I trust you do correctly)

    return <div>
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(coords)}</pre>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that I needed to re-render before seeing the changes!

Answer (score 0):

try useCallback

```
... 
const onSearch = useCallback(async () {
        if (city) {
            await apiGet(`/geo/1.0/direct?q=${city}`)
                .then(r => r.json())
                .then(r => setCoords({lat: r[0].lat, lon:r[0].lon})); // doesn't't set anything

            await console.log(coords) // console logs {}
            await apiGet(
                `/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${coords.lat}&lon=${coords.lon}&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts`
            )
                .then(r => r.json())
                .then(r => setForecast(r));
        }
    }, [coords]);
...
```

Refer: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Answer (score 0):

**setState()** operation is asynchronous in React. All that means that you can't rely on your new state values you apply in setState to be applied immediately.
Along with setState, **fetch()** is also asynchronous in nature.Hence, console.log  statement will not wait for the setState() or fetch() to get executed. In such a scenario, you can always handle it by a callback argument of setState().

```
           await apiGet(`/geo/1.0/direct?q=${city}`)
            .then(r => r.json())
            .then(r => setCoords(data => {lat: r[0].lat, lon:r[0].lon}))
```