# Jest does not continue after async method

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, async-await, jestjs

I have an async method triggered by a click event where I make a call to an API and then process the response, like this:

```
async confirmName () {
    const {name, description} = this.form;
    const [data, error] = await Pipelines.createPipeline({name, description});

    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        this.serviceError = true;
        return false;
    }

    this.idPipelineCreated = data.pipeline_id;
    return true;
}
```

The test looks like this:

```
test("API success", async () => {
    const ConfirmNameBtn = wrapper.find(".form__submit-name");
    await ConfirmNameBtn.vm.$emit("click");

    const pipelinesApi = new Pipelines();
    jest.spyOn(pipelinesApi, "createPipeline").mockResolvedValue({pipeline_id: 100});

    const {name, description} = wrapper.vm.form;

    pipelinesApi.createPipeline().then(data => {
        expect(wrapper.vm.pipelineNameServiceError).toBe(false);

        wrapper.setData({
            idPipelineCreated: data.pipeline_id
        });

        expect(wrapper.vm.idPipelineCreated).toBe(data.pipeline_id)
    }).catch(() => {})

})
```

A basic class mock:

```
export default class Pipelines {
    constructor () {}

    createPipeline () {}
}
```

I'm testing a success API call and I mock the API call returning a resolved promised. The problem is the coverage only covers the first two lines of the method, not the part where I assign the response of the API call. Is this the correct approach?

Edit:

Screenshot of coverage report:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix up `await` and `then/catch`. Prefer using `await` unless you have very special cases (see this [answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54575211/1376618):

```js
test("API success", async () => {
    const ConfirmNameBtn = wrapper.find(".form__submit-name");
    await ConfirmNameBtn.vm.$emit("click");

    const pipelinesApi = new Pipelines();
    jest.spyOn(pipelinesApi, "createPipeline").mockResolvedValue({pipeline_id: 100});

    const {name, description} = wrapper.vm.form;
    const data = await pipelinesApi.createPipeline();

    expect(wrapper.vm.pipelineNameServiceError).toBe(false);

    wrapper.setData({
        idPipelineCreated: data.pipeline_id
    });

    expect(wrapper.vm.idPipelineCreated).toBe(data.pipeline_id)
    expect(wrapper.vm.serviceError).toBe(false);
})
```

Comment: I have changed that bit, but still have the same issue, coverage of only the destructuring of the form and the api call.

Comment: Can you show the coverage report?

Comment: I added an screenshot of it.

Comment: Shouldn't you test `confirmName` call directly?

Comment: You mean calling the method inside the test? If I do that, it will trigger the real API call, not the mock one.

Comment: Then just mock the whole module and that's it

Comment: You mean the API module? It's there a way to call the component method but using an API mock?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242049/discussion-between-ismael-ordas-and-anatoly).

Comment: That's the whole idea of mocking, isn't it?