# JS not waiting for Promise to be fulfilled?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying for my application to wait for the promise to return before executing other code, which is dependant on that data. For this I am using `then()`, but it is not working as expected, as the next code is still being executed, before my values are being returned.

I am using Express to handle requests and Axios to make my own requests.

**index.js:**

```js
app.get('/api/guild/:serverId', async (req,res) => {
    bot.getGuild(req.params.serverId).then((response) => { // It should here wait for the promise before executing res.send(...)...
        res.send(response.data);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error) // Error: Returns that response is undefined
    });
});
```

**bot.js:**

```js
module.exports.getGuild = async function (id){
    axios.get(BASE_URL + `guilds/${id}`, {
        headers: { 
            'Authorization' : 'Bot ' + token // Send authorization header
        }
    }).then(function (response){ // Wait for response
        console.log("Returning guild data")
        return response; // Sending the response and also logging
    }).catch(function (error){
        console.log("Returning undefined.")
        return undefined; // This is not being used in my problem
    });
}
```

I already know that `getGuild(id)` is returning a working response. It also logs `Returning guild data` when returning the data. Yet this is being returned *after* index.js returning the error, that the response is undefined. Even though it should actually wait for the Promise to be fulfilled and then working with `response.data`.

Log:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at bot.getGuild.then (...\website\src\server\index.js:47:27)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Returning guild data
```

Comment: Avoid [mixing `async` code with `.then(…)` calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`then` is not needed in `async` functions because `await` is syntactic sugar for `then`.

`getGuild` doesn't return a promise from Axios, so it cannot be chained.

It should be:

```
module.exports.getGuild = function (id){
    return axios.get(BASE_URL + `guilds/${id}`, {
    ...
```

The use of `catch` in `getGuild` is a bad practice because it suppresses an error and prevents it from being handled in caller function.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Yes I added the catch out of panic after trying too much stuff, I guess. I will mark this as solved, when StackOverflow allows me to.

Comment: I call a `catch` like this a "try/hide" because that is what it does :) good note

Answer (score 1):

The getGuild function must wait for the axios promise in order to return a result:

```
try {

    let res = await axios.get(BASE_URL + `guilds/${id}`, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bot ' + token // Send authorization header
        }
    })

    console.log("Returning guild data")
    return res

} catch (exp) {
    console.log("Returning undefined.")
    return undefined;
}
```