# Is there another way of returning a value from this SQL without the use of a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the code I have tried, when I try to return `soc` it says it is undefined, I know this is because it is defined within a nested promise. My question is how can I return the result of my sql query without the use of a `.then` promise as I do not fully understand them and they're just causing me pain.

```
async function get_charge_level() {
    var config = {
            <config_settings>
        };
        sql.setDefaultConfig(config);
        await sql.execute( {
            query: "some query"
        } ).then(async function( id ) {

            await sql.execute( {
                query: "some other query"
            } ).then(async function( soc ) {
            })
        })

    return soc
}
```

Comment: Have look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). You're mixing the `await` operator with the promises. `await` waits for the promise to be resolved and returns the result.

Comment: Avoid [`await`ing a `.then(…)` chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572)! If you don't want to use `then`, just use `await` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using the `async-await` syntax, so just change as follows:

```js
async function get_charge_level() {
  var config = {
    //<config_settings>
  }
  sql.setDefaultConfig(config);
  let id = await sql.execute({
    query: "some query"
  })
  let soc = await sql.execute({
    query: "some other query"
  })
  return soc
}
```