# How to use Async/Await in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch, openid-connect

I have an index.js which gets data from a json file.
I export this function to my App.js where I want to store this data in another object.

configurations/index.js:

```
let config = (async () => {
    let data;
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
        if (
            typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
            (window.location.hostname.match('localhost') || window.location.hostname.match('127.0.0.1'))
        ) {
            data = require('./config.client.local.json');
        } else {
            data = require('./config.client.ip.json');
        }
    } else {
        data = fetch(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/config.client.json")
            .then(async res => await res.json());
    }
    return Object.assign({}, await data);
})();

export default config;
```

App.js

```
 import OIDC from 'oidc-client';
 import config from './configurations';
 window["UserManager"] = new OIDC.UserManager(config.oidc);
```

I have no idea how to get the data without using async/await

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: `.then(res => res.json());` [don't mix async/await with Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1218980), it's redundant and confusing.

Comment: Also, your config is a promise, even if you use `async/await`, so you either use `config.then(realConfigData => /* */)` or `await config`.

Comment: @EmileBergeron, is there a way so I can fetch this file(file is outside src) without using fetch?

Comment: Depending on your project's configuration, there are chances that you can just `import jsonConfig from '../config.client.json';` and parse this once at build time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `config` is a `Promise` which means that you can do this:

```
config.then(({ oidc }) => {
  window.UserManager = new OIDC.UserManager(oidc);
});
```

Comment: `window.UserManager`, the bracket syntax is not necessary.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Yes, that is true, I've edited the answer

Comment: It's also probably `config.then(({ oidc })` since it looks like `oidc` is a property of `config` based on what OP is trying to do.