# NodeJS Error Handling - Throwing error promise to try catch

Tags: node.js, error-handling, promise

im trying to get the promise error, and throw to the "try catch" to concentrate the return of the error in one place.

like this:

```
async schedule(req, res) {
        try {

            //here is the function that returns a promise
            service.search()
                .then(async data => {

                    if (data.length > 0) {   
                            res.status(200).json("OK!");                        
                    }
                })
                .catch(async error => {
                   //here i want to throw this error to the "try catch" to return the error message
                   throw new Error(error);                  
                })

        }
        catch (error) {
            res.status(400).json(error);
        };

    }
```

but when goes to "`throw new Error(error);`" gives me the message:

```
(node:15720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
    warning.js:27
```

someone could help me to understand what im doing wrong?

thank so much!

Rafael

**UPDATE**

based on the Marcos answer, i did:

```
async schedule(req, res) {
        try {

            const data = await service.search();                      

            if (data.length > 0) {   
                res.status(200).json("OK!");                        
            }               

        }
        catch (error) {
            res.status(400).json(error);
        };

  }
```

and worked... Now i understand how to handle this errors... thanks!

Comment: Avoid [passing `async` functions as `.then(…)` callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572)!

Comment: Bergi, in this case, what you think its the best way to do this? I dont have much experience with async functions.. thanks!

Comment: Just like what @Marcos wrote in his answer - use either style, but don't mix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either use `async/await` with a `try/catch` or `.then/.catch`, you don't mix both ways.

```
async schedule(req, res) {
    try {

        //here is the function that returns a promise
        // If service.search rejects, it will go to the `catch`
        const data = await service.search()


        if (data.length > 0) {   
            return res.status(200).json("OK!");                        
        }
        // do something here
        // res.status(400).send('Invalid data')
        // throw new Error('Invalid data')

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json(error);
    }

}
```

or

```
schedule(req, res) {
   service.search()
      .then(data => {

          if (data.length > 0) {   
                  res.status(200).json("OK!");                        
          }
      })
      .catch(error => {
          res.status(400).json(error);                 
      })
}
```

Comment: Hi Marcos thanks for the help!!  I just put a await in front of service.search to wait the function returns..! But worked! Thanks again!