# Javascript - multiple .then-clauses inside the executer of promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Im having trouble to understand the following javascript code:

```
/**
* Outputs the result of compiling a template.
*
* @module generator.generate
* @param  {Object}        config Configuration options
* @param  {Object|String} config.asyncapi AsyncAPI JSON or a string pointing to an AsyncAPI file.
* @param  {String}        config.target_dir Path to the directory where the files will be generated.
* @return {Promise}
*/
generator.generate = config => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 bundleAndApplyDefaults(config)
   .then((cfg) => {
     async function start () {
       await registerHelpers(cfg);
       await registerPartials(cfg);
       await generateDirectoryStructure(cfg);
     }

     start().then(resolve).catch(reject);
   })
   .catch(reject);
});
```

More specifically in which order the `.then`'s are called and what promise they belong to. I think that the first `.then` gets called when the method `bundleAndApplyDefaults(config)` is completed. But im not sure what where the parameter `cfg` comes from.

Inside the function `start()` gets called and the second `.then` with the resolve of the original promise gets executed, the original promise only has .catch(reject) outside the executor and no `.then` for success, as far as i know.

Hereby im also not sure, why there is a `.then` after the start method, when theres no actual promise.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: "*im not sure what where the parameter cfg comes from.*" it's what the promise returned by  `bundleAndApplyDefaults` will pass into the `then` when resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is horrible code, full of the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) and [mixing `async`/`await` syntax with `then` method calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572). It should simply be

```
generator.generate = async (config) => {
  const cfg = await bundleAndApplyDefaults(config);
  await registerHelpers(cfg);
  await registerPartials(cfg);
  await generateDirectoryStructure(cfg);
};
```

Comment: This is way better to understand, thanks! But isnt there a return statement missing, as seen in the comment `@return {Promise}`?

Comment: @NicO async functions always return a promise. Also, the original code also doesn't have an explicit return - it just returns a Promise that will not have any further values, it will just be resolved eventually.

Answer (score 1):

This is poorly written code. This is what the author meant to write:

```
generator.generate = config => bundleAndApplyDefaults(config).then(async (cfg) => {
    await registerHelpers(cfg);
    await registerPartials(cfg);
    await generateDirectoryStructure(cfg);
  });
```

This code works exactly like your code, just without the bloat.

The wrapping `new Promise()` is an antipattern, and comes here with the additional cost that you have to resolve/reject it by forwarding the values from the Promise that `start()` returns.

> im also not sure, why there is a `.then` after the start method, when theres no actual promise.

An `async` function returns a Promise.

Comment: I'd argue that (unncessarily) mixing `then` and `await` is still poor code :-)

Answer (score 0):

Because `start` is `async`, it will return an implicit promise.

The [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) has more information.