# .then method receives undefined instead of returned value after await nodejs

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I am new to Promises, and thought I have more or less understood the topic for now, but apparently not very well.

I am asking for an explanation of what is happening in the following, I think I have an understanding of what is happening, but **not why**...

**My misunderstanding is in this piece of code:**

```
(async () => {
            try{

                const result = await neoDB.getPatientById(requestedPatientID)
                .then (result => {
                    console.log('2----------------');   //VIEW CONSOLE OUTPUT
                    console.log(result);        //<---WHY RESULT IS UNDEFINED??    VIEW CONSOLE OUTPUT
                    resolve('Found Patient ' + requestedPatientID);
                    res.send(result);      //sending patient's data as a response. If no patient was found, TBD is sent
                });
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.log('-- in catch');
                console.log(error);
            }
        })();
```

**and neoDB.getPatientById(id):**

```
async function getPatientById(id){

    const session = driver.session();
    try {
        const result = await session.run('MATCH (p:Patient {id : ' + id + '}) RETURN p')
        .then(result => {

            const PatientJson = convertDBPatientObjToJson(result.records[0]._fields[0].properties)

            console.log(PatientJson);   //VIEW CONSOLE OUTPUT
            console.log('1----------------');   //VIEW CONSOLE OUTPUT
            return PatientJson;
        });
    }
    catch (error){
        console.log('-- in catch');
        console.log(error);
    }
    finally {
        await session.close()
    }
}
```

I understand that a promise is returned as resolved if there is a return, but why doesn't the code in the .then method (in the first piece of code) waits for the returned value?

**Console output:**

```
node localDB.js 
localDB-MS started on port: 3002

{id: 1, phone_number: 11111, a: patient1, b: 25, c: true}
1----------------
2----------------
undefined
```

As you can see the output timeline corresponds to the logic, but something is going wrong in the content of result.

Thanks for any help, I am trying to understand what's going on here, so please add a word or two :)

Comment: `getPatientById` doesn't return anything. `return PatientJson` is *inside a callback*, you still need to `return result`.

Comment: Avoid [`await`ing a `.then(…)` chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572)!