# Not able to getting the result in desired sequence while using async-await and promises in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have referenced so many solutions but I think my condition is quite different from what I have searched yet.
I am a newbie with async-await and promises.
I am creating a cron job function in nodeJS with MongoDB database.
I have a table named **'Device'**, in which I have a list of devices right now I have 5 records.
I have other tables mapped with the device table by **deviceId** i.e., **'Location'**, **'DeviceInfo'**, **'DailyStatus'**.
Here is my code:

```
// schedule tasks to be run on the server every sec
cron.schedule("*/1 * * * * *", function() { 
async function finalData() { //asyncronously final data
    function findDevices() { //find all devices
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Device.find((error, data) => {
          if (error) {
            reject("error in sending the data");
          } else {
            if (data.length > 0) {
              resolve(data); //get devices list successfully
            } else {
              reject("data length is ! > 0");
            }
          }
        });
      });
    }
    var dataNew = await findDevices().then(function (returnedData) {
        console.log('every second','findDevices')
      returnedData.forEach((element) => { //iteration perform properly
        async function callMyData() {
          var dataSpeed = await Location.findOne(
            { device: element.deviceId },
            function (error, data) {
              if (error) {
                console.log('error',error)
                return next(error);
              } else {
                return data.speed;
              }
            }
          ).sort({ _id: -1 });
          console.log(dataSpeed.speed,'dataSpeed') //first

          var dataIgnition = await DeviceInfo.findOne(
            { device: element.deviceId },
            function (error, data) {
              if (error) {
                console.log('error',error)
                return next(error);
              } else {
                return data.ignition;
              }
            }
          ).sort({ _id: -1 });
          console.log(dataIgnition.ignition,'dataIgnition') //second

          var dataDailyStatus = await DailyStatus.findOne(
            { device: element.deviceId },
            function (error, data) {
              if (error) {
                console.log("error", error);
                return next(error);
              } else {
                 return data.status;
              }
            }
          ).sort({ _id: -1 });
          console.log(dataDailyStatus.status,'dataDailyStatus') //third

        }
        return callMyData().then(function (string) {
          console.log("next iteration"); //after every interation
        });
      });
    });
  }
  finalData().then(function (string) {});
});
```

My cron is working fine and also getting the device records properly.
But I am not able to get the sequence of the records as per the requirement.
What I am expecting is:

```
every second findDevices
0 'dataSpeed'
0 dataIgnition
Idle dataDailyStatus
next iteration
0 'dataSpeed'
1 dataIgnition
Stop dataDailyStatus
next iteration
0 'dataSpeed'
1 dataIgnition
Idle dataDailyStatus
next iteration
0 'dataSpeed'
0 dataIgnition
Stop dataDailyStatus
next iteration
0 'dataSpeed'
1 dataIgnition
Idle dataDailyStatus
next iteration
Finished
```

What I actually get is:

```
every second findDevices
Finished
0 'dataSpeed'
0 'dataSpeed'
0 'dataSpeed'
0 'dataSpeed'
0 dataIgnition
0 'dataSpeed'
1 dataIgnition
1 dataIgnition
0 dataIgnition
1 dataIgnition
Idle dataDailyStatus
next iteration
Stop dataDailyStatus
Idle dataDailyStatus
Stop dataDailyStatus
next iteration
next iteration
next iteration
Idle dataDailyStatus
next iteration
```

Can you guys please help me out how I can achieve the requested sequence as I am quite new with async-await and promises.

Comment: When calling `findOne`, you are passing a callback instead of using promises. You won't be able to `await` the result.

Comment: [Avoid `forEach`!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/1048572) And [try not to mix `await` and `.then(…)` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572).

Comment: Thanks for your time @Bergi, I have tried to use promises with findOne and hurray! I got my result.

Comment: Hold on! I am getting the Promise <pending>. Is this right?

Comment: every second findDevices
Promise { <pending> } 'dataSpeed'
Promise { <pending> } 'dataIgnition'
Promise { <pending> } 'dataDailyStatus'
Promise { <pending> } 'dataSpeed'
Promise { <pending> } 'dataIgnition'
Promise { <pending> } 'dataDailyStatus'
Promise { <pending> } 'dataSpeed'
Promise { <pending> } 'dataIgnition'
Promise { <pending> } 'dataDailyStatus'
Promise { <pending> } 'dataSpeed'
Promise { <pending> } 'dataIgnition'
Promise { <pending> } 'dataDailyStatus'
Finished

Comment: @Bergi can you please guide me to solve this Promise { <pending> } issue.  I am unable to get the fix.

Comment: You'll need to put an `await` between the promise and the `console.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your desired result with simpler code.

I have rewritten `finalData` with a library I created, [rubico](https://github.rubico.land). rubico removes a lot of boilerplate surrounding Promises.

```js
const { pipe, fork, tryCatch, switchCase, map, get, gt } = require('rubico')

const identity = x => x

const findDevices = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Device.find((err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(data))
})

const getLocationByDeviceID = deviceId => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Location.findOne(
    { device: deviceId },
    (err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(data),
  ).sort({ _id: -1 })
})

const getDeviceInfoByDeviceID = deviceId => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  DeviceInfo.findOne(
    { device: deviceId },
    (err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(data),
  ).sort({ _id: -1 })
})

const getDailyStatusByDeviceID = deviceId => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  DailyStatus.findOne(
    { device: deviceId },
    (err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(data),
  ).sort({ _id: -1 })
})

const finalData = pipe([
  tryCatch(
    findDevices, // try findDevices()
    () => { throw new Error('error in sending the data') }, // on error, throw a new Error
  ),
  switchCase([
    gt(get('length'), 0), identity, // if data length is greater than 0, send it through (x => x)
    () => { throw new Error('data length is ! > 0') }, // else throw a new Error
  ]),
  map(fork.series([ // for each device, log speed, ignition, dailyStatus in series
    pipe([
      get('deviceId'), // device => device.deviceId
      getLocationByDeviceID, // deviceId => getLocationByDeviceID(deviceId) => location
      get('speed'), // location => location.speed
      x => console.log(x, 'dataSpeed')
    ]),
    pipe([
      get('deviceId'), // get device.deviceId
      getDeviceInfoByDeviceID, // deviceId => getDeviceInfoByDeviceID(deviceId) => deviceInfo
      get('ignition'), // deviceInfo => deviceInfo.ignition
      x => console.log(x, 'dataIgnition')
    ]),
    pipe([
      get('deviceId'), // get device.deviceId
      getDailyStatusByDeviceID, // deviceId => getDailyStatusByDeviceID(deviceId) => dailyStatus
      get('status'), // dailyStatus => dailyStatus.status
      x => console.log(x, 'dataDailyStatus')
    ]),
  ])), // [device] => [{ speed, ignition, status }]
])

cron.schedule('*/1 * * * * *', finalData)
```

Comment: Thanks @richytong, but I am getting an error with the library you have mentioned.                 const mapAsyncIterable = (fn, x) => (async function*() {
                                                   ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
Please guide

Comment: what version of node are you using?

Comment: you'll want at least node [v10.3](https://node.green/#ES2018-features-Asynchronous-Iterators-async-generators)

Comment: I have installed my node v8.9.0.

Comment: are you able to upgrade?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to upgrade to version you have suggested.

Comment: If you're going to upgrade, I recommend getting onto 14.3.0 so you don't have to worry about upgrading for a while. Also has latest features (autocomplete repl)

Comment: you can always check the latest recommended versions of node on their website [here](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214795/discussion-between-suhail-khan-and-richytong).