# How to return a promise with entity type in Nest Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am coding a function that return a promise with a given type of data.
My entity name is `Groups` and i want to return a array of Groups `Groups[]`
This is my function

```
async filterGroupsByAvailableSpots (groups: Groups[] ) :Promise<Groups[]> {
    let groupsAvailableToMatch : Groups[] = [] ;
    
    let searchAvailableGroupsLoop = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      groups.forEach((group, index, array) => {
        this.getStudentsByActiveGroup (group.id)
          .then((students) => {
            //If the group have spots to match
            if (students.length < 6) {
              groupsAvailableToMatch.push(group)
            }
            // Stop FLag    
            if (index === array.length -1) {
              resolve(groupsAvailableToMatch);
            } 
          })
      });
    });

    return searchAvailableGroupsLoop;
  }
```

But Im facing an error in the return promise

```
let searchAvailableGroupsLoop: Promise<unknown>
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Groups[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2740)
```

Comment: (∩⌣̀_⌣́) that async looks suspicious, you're not using `await` inside your function, try not to mix them https://blog.logrocket.com/async-await-in-typescript/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385676/whats-wrong-with-awaiting-a-promise-chain/54387912#54387912

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think TS is not able to infer the type for the returned variable, try specifying the type when creating the promise

```
  let searchAvailableGroupsLoop = new Promise<Groups[]>((resolve, reject) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve your Promise for every case. If in your groups array there are none "Stop flags" your promise resolves to `{}`. So resolve with an empty array or reject with an error if that suits your requirements better.

```
async filterGroupsByAvailableSpots (groups: Groups[] ) :Promise<Groups[]> {
let groupsAvailableToMatch : Groups[] = [] ;

let searchAvailableGroupsLoop = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  groups.forEach((group, index, array) => {
    this.getStudentsByActiveGroup (group.id)
      .then((students) => {
        //If the group have spots to match
        if (students.length < 6) {
          groupsAvailableToMatch.push(group)
        }
        // Stop FLag    
        if (index === array.length -1) {
          resolve(groupsAvailableToMatch);
        } 
      })
  });
  resolve([]); // add this line or reject("Error");
});

return searchAvailableGroupsLoop;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your help, but Im still getting the same error.