# Error with sample firebase code (docRef.get().then(() => {...});

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Sample firebase code, not working

Hello, I tried the sample code (from here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Their base code, I get an error.

Here is my adaptation (also has error):

```
var docRef = this.firestore.collection('Clients').doc(clientId);
docRef.get().then( doc =>
  {
    let test = doc.data() as ClientModel
    clientName = test.ClientName;
    console.log(test);
  });
```

The 'then following from docRef.get()' produces this error:

> Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable<DocumentSnapshot>'.ts(2339)

From my research, it appears with angular I am using an observable, however, when I tried to convert to a promise it just froze.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think my issue was not awaiting it once turned to a promise.

Answer (score 1):

By using `await` and `then` you're using an anti pattern, please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385676/whats-wrong-with-awaiting-a-promise-chain):

> Under the hood, async/await is just promises.
>
> That is, when you have some code that looks like:
>
> ```
> const result = await myAsyncFunction();   
> console.log(result):
> ```
>
> That's exactly the same as writing:
>
> ```
> myAsyncFunction().then(data => {
>    const result = data; 
>    console.log(result); 
> });
> ```
>
> The reason then - that you shouldn't mix async/await and .then chains
>
> - is because it's confusing.
>
> It's better to just pick one style, and stick to it.
>
> And while you're picking one - you might as well pick async/await -
> it's more understandable.

`docRef.get()` already returns a [promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#get) (that's why in the examples you can see the `then`/`catch`), `toPromise()` converts an observable into a Promise, however as mentioned `docRef.get()` already returns a promise which means you're making a Promise of another Promise.

If you're already familiar with Angular, I recommend you to use [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) which is an implementation of the Firebase SDK and can help you to perform the task with the use of Observables rather than callbacks.

Comment: Thank you. But, my issue is that I did not have a then option after get(). I am using angular 10. The only way I got the then to work is by adding to promise. But, I understand what you are saying about await....  it made a promise, I don’t need to wait on it, it promised it would do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I believe my issue was that I had not awaited the toPromise() results.

I updated my code to the following:

```
    var clientName = 'Unknown;'
    this.spinnerService.SetSpinner(true);
    var docRef = await this.firestore.collection('Clients').doc(clientId);
    await docRef.get().toPromise()
      .then((doc) => 
      {
          clientName = (doc.data() as ClientModel).ClientName
      })
      .catch((error) => 
        {
          console.log(error);
          alert(error);
        })
      .finally(() =>
        {
            this.spinnerService.SetSpinner(false);
        });

    return clientName;
```