# Promise.all is not waiting for state to be updated

Tags: react-native, promise, react-hooks, use-state

I have a function that uploads multiple files one at a time and for that, I have to wait till all of them are uploaded and then I want to call a function.

I've two hooks

```
    const [attachments, setAttachments] = useState([]);
    const [uploadedAttachments, setuploadedAttachments] = useState([]);
```

`attachments` contains the selected file and then when a file is uploaded I'm storing some metadata about it in `uploadedAttachments` which I need to send with another call.

So on the upload button press, I'm calling this function:

```
async function uploadAttachments(userID, id) {
        await Promise.all(
            attachments.map(async (val, index) => {
                await services.uploadAttachment(val, userID, id).then((res) => {
                    setuploadedAttachments([...uploadedAttachments, { "name": res.name, "size": res.size }])
                }).catch((error) => {
                    Alert.alert("Error", error)
                })
            })).then(() => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(uploadedAttachments))
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.log("ERROR: " + e)
            })
}
```

The `JSON.stringify(uploadedAttachments)` prints `[]` but if I `console.log` the `res` before `setuploadedAttachments` is called I see I'm getting the response and that means that the `setuploadedAttachments` is being updated but the place where I'm print it shows me empty array. So, how do I make sure that it `await` and so that I can see it when the `Promise.all` is finished?

**UPDATE**

My question is not a duplicate of [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

I'm waiting for all the promises to fulfill. Each promise when return me some data I add it to an array which I'm handling using the `useState` hook. Yes, it's not reflecting the changes immediately and I have tried putting it in the `useEffect` hook as suggested in the supposed duplicate question.

```
useEffect(() => {
     setuploadedAttachments([...uploadedAttachments, { "name": res.name, "size": res.size }])
}, [])
```

It shows the alert with `Error` in the title but no error message. In short, it's not working.

**UPDATE 2**

Based on the comments I did

```
async function uploadAttachments(userID, id) {
        await Promise.all(
            attachments.map(async (val, index) => {
                await services.uploadAttachment(val, userID, id).then((res) => {
                    return res
                }).catch((error) => {
                    Alert.alert("Error", error)
                })
            })).then((responses) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(responses))
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.log("ERROR: " + e)
            })
}
```

The `services.uploadAttachment` function is

```
async function uploadAttachment(val, userID, id) {

    let fullURL = BASE_URL + '/uploadFile'
    
    const data = new FormData()
    data.append(...

    const config = {
       ...
    };

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        axios.post(fullURL, data, config).then((response) => {
            res(response.data)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
            Alert.alert("Error Occured", error);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: It *does* wait, but `setuploadedAttachments` does not update the `const uploadedAttachments` variable that you have in scope

Comment: @Bergi yes, so how do I update it? The question that was tagged as a duplicate does not answer my question as it uses the `useEffect` and I have to wait till all promises are fulfilled and then using the updated state to do additional functionality.

Comment: Just don't use the updated state. Return the upload responses from your `then` callback, and access the result of the `Promise.all` promise

Comment: Also the `useEffect` that was suggested as a solution in the duplicate was supposed to contain the "additional functionality" you're talking about, not the `setuploadedAttachments` call. It's an effect that should run whenever the `uploadedAttachments` (and possibly the `attachments`) state change, taking them as dependencies.

Comment: I chose the duplicate mostly because it explains why `console.log(JSON.stringify(uploadedAttachments))` cannot print the results you expected.

Comment: @Bergi I'm a bit new to javascript/react rules, so when you say return responses from `then` callback, return it to where? Because the `res` I'm getting with `Promise.all` is returning one-by-one and not a combined result so I need to store the result of one promise when I get it somewhere right? Is it possible to add an answer regarding what you're suggesting? If not then can you please reopen the question so that others can find it to answer? Because I'm not sure what new to add if I add a new question.

Comment: @Bergi All I want to do is simply wait till all files are uploaded and then use the response of each of those files as soon as the last file is finished uploading.

Comment: I mean `Promise.all(attachments.map(async (val) => { … return response; })).then(responses => { console.log(responses); })`. Also try to [avoid mixing `.then()` and `await` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi I did exactly like you just described. `.then((res) => { return res ... })).then((responses) => { console.log(JSON.stringify(responses)) ...` and I get `[null,null]` printed in the log.

Comment: Did you unnest the promise chain and actually `return` the value from the `async` function that is the `map` callback? It seems you're still returning `undefined`.

Comment: @Bergi just update my question, kindly see UPDATE 2 where it shows exactly how I did it.

Comment: Ah, yes. The callback should be either `async (val) => { try { return await services.uploadAttachment(val, userID, id); } catch (error) { Alert.alert("Error", error); } }` or `(val) => { return services.uploadAttachment(val, userID, id).catch((error) => { Alert.alert("Error", error); }); }` - notice the `return`s in both cases.

Comment: @Bergi thank you so much for your help & patience :D This last comment solved it for me. Feel free to add it as an answer I'll accept it.