# Javascript recursive promise is firing the catch() twice, having a hard time following

Tags: javascript, promise, discord.js

I wrote a function in Discord.js v13 that expects user input. If the input is invalid, it needs to re-prompt them again, and the original promise should no longer be considered.

If the user takes longer than `timeoutSeconds`, then it throws an `InputTimeout` error.

What happens in practice, which I don't understand, is this:

1. getResponse(...) is executed
2. User is prompted for input
3. User supplies invalid input
4. User is informed of invalid input, and is re-prompted
5. If no input is supplied, an `InputTimeout` error is thrown from the **first** request ***and*** the **second** request

What I wish to happen is:

1. getResponse(...) is executed
2. User is prompted for input
3. User supplies invalid input
4. User is informed of invalid input, and is re-prompted
5. If no input is supplied, an `InputTimeout` error is thrown for the new request only

Here is what I think is happening... The second prompt is throwing the `InputTimeout` error which is causing the `catch()` handler from the first Promise to fire off. If that's true, then I am confused, because I thought if `then()` runs, then it's because no error was thrown. So why is `catch()` catching errors from the `then()` function? Should put `catch()` first, before `then()`? Is this an issue with the order I've chained the functions?

```
async getResponse(user, timeoutSeconds, channel = null) {
        if (channel == null) {
            const msg = await user.send(this.promptMessage);
            channel = msg.channel;
        }
        return await channel
            .awaitMessages({
                max: 1,
                time: timeoutSeconds * 1000,
                errors: ["time"],
            })
            .then(async (messages) => {
                if (messages.size == 1) {
                    const message = messages.values().next().value;
                    if (this.validator(message)) {
                        await user.send(this.successMessage);
                        return this.formatter(message);
                    } else {
                        await user.send(this.errorMessage);
                        await this.getResponse(
                            user,
                            timeoutSeconds,
                            channel
                        );
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch(async (e) => {
                console.error(e);
                await channel.send(this.timeoutMessage);
                throw new InputTimeout();
            });
    }
```

Comment: Avoid [mixing `await` with `.then(…)` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was in fact the order of the `.then()` and `.catch()`. Since I was only concerned with catching errors from the `awaitMessages()` function, I should've chained it to that first, followed by the `.then()`.

By putting `catch()` after `then()`, I was catching errors from my `then()` function.

Doh!

###### New solution, which also gets rid of `.then()` and `.catch()` as suggested by community:

```
try {
    let messages = await channel.awaitMessages({
        max: 1,
        time: timeoutSeconds * 1000,
        errors: ["time"],
    });
    messages = Array.from(messages.values());
    if (messages.length == 1) {
        const message = messages[0];
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        if (this.validator(message)) {
            await user.send(this.successMessage);
            return this.formatter(message);
        } else {
            await user.send(this.errorMessage);
            return this.getResponse( // note I removed "await" here to prevent nested errors
                user,
                timeoutSeconds,
                channel
            );
        }
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    await channel.send(this.timeoutMessage);
    throw new InputTimeout();
}
```

Comment: Mixing `await` with `.then()` is an error-prone practice.

Comment: You also might want to [use `.then(…, …)` instead of `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572). But yeah, if your `catch` handler always re-throws an error, `.catch(…).then(…)` will also work fine.

Comment: @Pointy By that you mean the `return await` part, or the `await` within the `.then()` function? Or both?

Comment: The whole point of `async` functions and `await` is to make using Promise objects easier. Instead of `.then()` callbacks, you can use `await`, which will essentially turn the rest of your function into a `.then()` function body.

Comment: @Pointy Ok, I am following. I got confused as to why they both existed but it looks like it's just two of the same thing, just different syntax. I prefer `try / catch` so I just updated the function to use that across the board. Thanks!