# How to access a variable used to hold an array of data in a async function

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
//service class
    async importExcel(userId, file){
      const business = await this.getBusinessByUserId(Types.ObjectId(userId));
      let errorData = [];
      readXlsxFile(file, {schema}).then(async ({rows, errors}) => {
        if(errors.length === 0){
          await this.excelUploadQueue.add({
            rows,
            business
          })
        }
        errors.forEach((error) => {
          const errors = {
            column: error.column,
            value: error.value,
            reason: error.reason,
          }
          errorData.push(errors)
        });
        console.log(errorData); can access the errorData here
      }) 
      console.log(errorData); cannot access it here, i want to access it here so that i
      return errorData; // can return it here to my controller
   
     }
```

//controller

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'
  , {
    storage: diskStorage({
      destination: './csv',
      filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix + "-" + file.originalname)
      }
    })
  }
  ))
  @Post('/import-excel/employee')
  @ApiOperation({summary: 'upload exployee data via excel'})
  async uploadExcel(
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
    @Request() req
    ){
      const { id: userId } = req.user;
      return await this.businessService.importExcel(userId, file.path);
  }
```

How can i go abt it,been on it for some hours....When i apply a settimeout like the below code
setTimeout(() => {
console.log(errorData) // i could access it but its not returning to my controller
}, 100);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: "async forEach" are two words [that don't go very well together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop). In general I'd avoid `.forEach()` where possible. But that being said, your specific `.forEach()` doesn't await anything, so there is no reason for it to be `async` in the first place.

Comment: i was actually doing sth on it that was why it was there...will remove it now..thanks for bringing my awareness to it

Comment: have removed the async from the forEach and its still the same thing

Comment: My second comment was just a side note. Your main problem is explained in the post linked in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

[Don't mix `async`/`await` syntax with `.then()` calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572). Just write

```
async importExcel(userId, file) {
  const business = await this.getBusinessByUserId(Types.ObjectId(userId));
  const {rows, errors} = await readXlsxFile(file, {schema});
//                       ^^^^^
  if (errors.length === 0) {
    await this.excelUploadQueue.add({
      rows,
      business
    })
  }
  const errorData = errors.map(error => ({
    column: error.column,
    value: error.value,
    reason: error.reason,
  }));
  console.log(errorData); // can access the errorData here
  return errorData; // and can return it here to my controller
}
```

The problem is not even related to the `forEach` loop, you simply were [trying to access `errorData` outside of the `then` callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572). And btw, [never use an `async` callback to `forEach`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/1048572) - easily fixed in your case since the callback didn't actually do anything asynchronous (though I still wonder why you need this at all - you're creating new objects with exactly the same properties as the errors, maybe just `return errors` directly?).

Comment: thanks alot....i also thought of it but was so disturbed to not think very well....it has worked ..thanks very much

Comment: there are still some error data that i dont need to be displayed that was why i used the foreach to take out what i needed..thanks...your solution solve my issue