# How to set a state in React Native in a nested asynchronous for loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, async-await

I want this code snippet to loop through an array of generic locations that includes cafe's, bars, stores, etc. On each iteration I run it through a google places api that finds every location with that keyword passed in that's open and for each result, I want it to add each result from the api to a state called placesOpen. So far it's able to get the locations no problem but the state is not being updated.

```
 Geocoder.from(location).then((json) => {
        const locResult = json.results[0].geometry.location;;
        genericLocations.forEach(async (type) => {
          const response = await fetch(
            `google places url`
          );
          const data = await response.json();
          data["results"].forEach((result) => {
            setPlacesOpen(placesOpen => [result["name"],...placesOpen]);
          });
        });
      })
```

Comment: What makes you think state is not updated? Did you verify the `data.results` that you actually got back? Did the code run without errors?

Comment: Btw, [don't mix `async`/`await` with `.then(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572), and [don't use `forEach` for asynchronous code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi I console logged it later on and it returns empty

Comment: Where exactly? What does "later on" mean? Did you actually log the old state due to a stale closure?

Comment: Include the full component

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be making many unnecessary component updates.

Why not do this?

```js
 Geocoder.from(location).then((json) => {
        const locResult = json.results[0].geometry.location;;
        genericLocations.forEach(async (type) => {
          const response = await fetch(
            `google places url`
          );
          const data = await response.json();

          const placesToOpen = data.results
          setPlacesOpen(current => [...current, ...placesToOpen]);
        });
      })
```

This will do only one `setState` instead of multiple ones. This should work and should update your local state.