# How to define a async-Function?

Tags: javascript, runtime

how can i define a function, that is called asynchronously?

```js
async function getPosts() {
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){}
    console.log("loop done.");
}

console.log("start");
getPosts();
console.log("end");
```

**the result is**:
start
loop done.
end


i was **expecting**:
start
end
loop done

i expect that, because the function "getPosts" is declared as "async". 
so the we dont wait until the function is finished.

How do i have to adjust my code to get the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

The async function could be the one calling another function that returns a `Promise`. Inside the `Promise` you could put a `setTimeout` instead of the for loop and finall make the call with `asyncCall`:

```js
function getPosts() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('done.');
    }, 2000);
  });
}


async function asyncCall() {
  var result = await getPosts();
  console.log(result);
}

console.log("start");
asyncCall();
console.log("end");
```

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why your code don't do the "async" thing, it's because of the way js threads works. A FOR loop will use the main thread to do the job soooo, the code will wait it finish de loop. The @shys answer works, but without the loop.
If you want a working async, take a look at the [WebWorker api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API)

Comment: Thank you. But how is the fetch()-Method implemented? The fetch-Method doesn't use the main-thread? Because i have to wait for the result.

Comment: ok, talking about [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) it's a different thing. Fetch is kind of a browser code, so it will run outside the main thread till it finish. Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046841/proper-way-to-make-api-fetch-post-with-async-await)

Comment: See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/rxk16o7n/) of how call a function, run some code and at the end, waits for the request if it's not already returned.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up what Mauricio Sipmann and shrys correctly told: *An asynchronous function is a function which operates asynchronously via the event loop* (see [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)). In order to continue executing the calling context of your `async function getPosts()`, i. e. with `console.log("end")`, the event loop must be given a chance to pause the execution of `getPosts()`, e. g. with this variant of your function:

```js
function sleep(ms) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)) }

async function getPosts() {
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { await sleep(3) } // pause for 3 ms
    console.log("loop done.");
}

console.log("start");
getPosts();
console.log("end");
```

> But how is the fetch()-Method implemented?

`fetch()` likely contains such an `await` statement, so that the event loop can continue executing while `fetch()` is waiting for the HTTP response.